# Store result of Select query to use later in sql file PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

I have PostgreSQL database. I run a sql file using PSQL command:

```
psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:port/dbname < filename.sql
```

My sql file looks like:

```
delete from records where id = 1;
delete from recordsinfo where recordsinfoid IN (select recordsinfoid from records where id = 1);
```

But I have a foreign key dependency:

> 'records' FOREIGN KEY (recordsinfoid) REFERENCES
>   recordsinfo(recordsinfoid)

So I cannot have the subquery in the second delete statement as the records would have got deleted in the first delete statement.

Also I cannot put the second delete statement first because it would cause foreign key violation.

How do I delete all entries in recordsinfo corresponding to the subquery 'select recordsinfoid from records where id = 1' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    recordsinfoids INTEGER[];
    i INTEGER;
BEGIN

    recordsinfoids := ARRAY(select recordsinfoid from records where id = 1);

    delete from records where id = 1;

    FOREACH i IN ARRAY recordsinfoids
    LOOP 
        delete from recordsinfo where recordsinfoid = i;
    END LOOP;

END $$;
```

Basically prefetch the values in an array, and then later delete

Answer (score 2):

Use a data-modifying CTE:

```
with d as (
      delete from records
      where id = 1
      returning *
     )
delete from recordsinfo
    where recordsinfoid in (select recordsinfoid from d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use temporary table as a record buffer:

```
create temp table tmp_records
as
select recordsinfoid from records where id = 1;

delete from records where id = 1;
delete from recordsinfo where recordsinfoid IN (select recordsinfoid from tmp_records);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cursor to fetch the recordsinfoid  from  records.
make a string by appending recordsinfoid by seperating ','.
make delete query using the created string,
execute the query using exec()

I am using mssql .